# PyQT5. Как передать сигнал из динамически созданного QGraphicsPixmapItem в QTableWidget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, сигналы-слоты

Суть проблемы:

- имеется модуль 'interface.py' основной, он запускается и в нем построен дизайн окна.
- так же есть модуль 'classes.py' в нем прописаны классы объектов и в них переопределённые функции.

Есть `class MyOBJ(QGraphicsPixmapItem)` объекты из этого класса создаются динамически во время выполнения программы и каждый новый объект реагирует на события мыши. Естественно находятся внутри `QGraphicsScene` и `QgraphicsView`.

Сокращенный код из **classes.py**:

```
class MyOBJ(QGraphicsPixmapItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setPixmap(QPixmap('dot.png'))
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        pass  # тут всякие разные конструкции
    super().mousePressEvent(event)
```

Есть класс `class MyTableFrames(QTableWidget)` созданный из него объект находится внутри `QDockWidget`, который в свою очередь является виджетом главного окна `QMainWindow` в модуле 'interface.py'

Сокращенный код из **classes.py**:

```
class MyTableFrames(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setColumnCount(7500)
        self.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(20)
        self.horizontalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(20)
        self.setRowCount(1)
        self.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.setRowHeight(0, 36)
        self.setEditTriggers(QTableWidget.NoEditTriggers)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print('Ok')
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == 1:
            self.setItem(self.currentRow(), self.currentColumn(), QTableWidgetItem("•"))
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)
```

Проблема в том, что я не понимаю каким способом передать событие мыши из `MyOBJ` в `MyTableFrames`, что бы при клике мышкой по `MyOBJ` в таблице `MyTableFrames` заданной ячейке (пусть будет 1) печаталась точка `"•"` или просто какой-то символ.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Минимальный вряд ли получится. Это 3 отдельных файла связанных между собой целой паутиной событий и функций. Только если куда-то залить исходники для тестирования.
Я догадываюсь, что ответ на мой вопрос кроется в сигналах/слотах, но как работать с этими sender и connect - никак не могу понять.

Comment: Пытаюсь через пользовательский сигнал сделать. Сигнал не проходит.

Создал сигнал:

class MySignal(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    signal_1 = pyqtSignal()
    print('signal IN')

В класс MyOBJ(QGraphicsPixmapItem):

добавил

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.sig = MySignal()
        self.sig.signal_1.emit()

В класс MyTableFrames(QTableWidget):

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print('signal OUT Ok')

Не получается, где то ошибка.

Comment: я, к сожалению, не смогу вам помочь пока вы не предоставите минимально-воспроизводимый пример. То что вы написали в комментарии, содержит моно ошибок.

Comment: S. Nick, в первую очередь хочу поблагодарить за отклик.
Постараюсь воспроизвести проблему в демонстрационном консольном варианте, это будет самый простой способ.
Маленький вопрос: вариант кода написать как "Комментировать" или "Ответить на собственный вопрос"? В комментариях нет форматирования кода.

Comment: нет, ниже вашего вопроса есть метка `править`, нажимаете на нее и добавляете обновления в вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Решено!**

При объявлении класса виджета таблицы создается пользовательский сигнал (в модуле *classes.py*):

```
class MyTableFrames(QTableWidget):
    TF_sign = pyqtSignal()  # сигнал для передачи в граф.вид
    def __init__(self):
```

Здесь же в этом классе в переопределенное событие мыши прописываю имитацию сигнала:

```
def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
    self.TF_sign.emit()  # создаем сигнал для граф.вида
```

В главном модуле (*interface.py*) в блоке *main* прописываю соединение сигнала таблицы со слотом в граф.виде (через всё дерево предок/потомок):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    # передаем сигналы в слоты
    window.tl_frames_table.TF_sign.connect(window.graphicView.tab_sel_slot)
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

В блоке граф.вида в модуле *classes.py* прописываю соответствующий слот/функцию:

```
class MyGraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self)
    def tab_sel_slot(self):  # слот приема сигнала от таблицы кадров
        print('signal OK')
```

Передача сигнала между виджетами окна через разные модули/файлы работает как часы.

Comment: проверить нет возможности, но это уже похоже на правду.

Answer (score 1):

> Проблема в том, что я не понимаю каким способом передать событие мыши
> из MyOBJ в MyTableFrames, что бы при клике мышкой по MyOBJ в таблице
> MyTableFrames заданной ячейке

Для того, чтобы ваш графический элемент сцены имел возможность испускать сигналы
надо его наследовать не только от QGraphicsPixmapItem, но и от QGraphicsObject:

```
class MyOBJ(QGraphicsObject, QGraphicsPixmapItem):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self):
        QGraphicsObject.__init__(self) # self передаем только сюда!
        QGraphicsPixmapItem.__init__(None) # а здесь просто конструируем

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        # Испускаем сигнал
        self.clicked.emit()
```

Далее, как обычно:

```
myObj = MyOBJ()
myObj.clicked.connect( ... )
```

Comment: Спасибо. Буду иметь ввиду. Уже реализовал и в одну и другую сторону. Из таблицы в граф.вид и из граф.вида в таблицу.